# Consultar dados relacionados sem repetições

Tags: sql, mysqli, inner-join

Preciso listar todos os dados da tabela CONTRATO, mas somente quando na tabela COMPROMISSO **`blocker = 1`**:

```
CONTRATO   COMPROMISSO
codigos    codgerado blocker
3315       1102         2
3317       1105         1
3318       1108         1
3320       3315         2
7726       3317         1
           3318         1
           3320         1
           7726         1
           8801         2
           8802         2
           9907         2
```

Estou tentando assim: (sem sucesso)

```
SELECT * FROM contrato LEFT JOIN compromisso ON compromisso.codGerado = contrato.codigos WHERE compromisso.blocker = '1';
```

Na tabela CONTRATO só existirão códigos que venham da tabela COMPROMISSO, porém a tabela COMPROMISSO é muito mais cheia e também somente na tabela COMPROMISSO tem a coluna `blocker` que servirá para dizer se um **código** foi "inutilizado" ou não.

**Como poderei listar os dados da tabela CONTRATO somente com os códigos que existem nela e na tabela COMPROMISSO, mas somente onde `blocker = 1`?**

Obrigado

Comment: Se quer apenas os códigos que existam em ambas as tabelas no lugar de RIGH JOIN utilize INNER JOIN.

Comment: @anonimo: Preciso listar todos os dados da tabela CONTRATO, mas somente quando na tabela COMPROMISSO blocker = 1:

Comment: Ou seja se um contrato não existir em compromisso então não deverá ser listado (já que blocker não seria 1)?

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar o `inner join` mesmo, se você quer analisar os contratos.

```
SELECT *
FROM
  contrato INNER JOIN compromisso ON compromisso.codGerado = contrato.codigos 
WHERE
  compromisso.blocker = '1';
```

Dessa forma, vai trazer só quando existir na tabela CONTRATO e que exista na tabela COMPROMISSO e que o blocker é 1. Os compromisso que não tem contrato não traz.

Answer (score 0):

Se você estiver preocupado com as repetições das linhas de CONTRATO, faça da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT DISTINCT C.codigos, C.xyz, C.abc /*etc., com os campos de CONTRATO*/
FROM contrato C
LEFT JOIN compromisso CP ON C.codigos = CP.codgerado
WHERE CP.blocker = 1;
```